# Facing javapath error while executing appium script

Tags: java, selenium, appium, appium-android

I have Given Correct JAVA_Home path: `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\bin`

Able to run the Normal JAVA program. But getting an issue while executing Mobile Test script using Appium.

**Console**:

```
remote stacktrace: UnknownError: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. 

Original error: Could not sign with default certificate.

Original error Command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\bin\bin\java.exe' not found. Is it installed?
    at getResponseForW3CError (C:\Users\venky\AppData\Local\Programs\Appium\resources\app\node_modules\appium\node_modules\appium-base-driver\lib\protocol\errors.js:804:9)
    at asyncHandler (C:\Users\venky\AppData\Local\Programs\Appium\resources\app\node_modules\appium\node_modules\appium-base-driver\lib\protocol\protocol.js:392:37)
```

Comment: The correct path for `JAVA_HOME` would be `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131` i.e. one level above `bin`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`JAVA_HOME` should be `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131`, without the `bin` part.  Note that your program is trying to run `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\bin\bin\java.exe` - the `bin\bin` is wrong.